# how can i get the session attribute in desired type

Tags: java, servlets

from another java application, i had already set my attribute to this:

```
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
     session.setAttribute("SessionUser", userName);
```

I'm not sure how to parse a specific attribute into a string.

```
String query = "SELECT title, first, last, email FROM member WHERE email="+**??**;
```

Comment: The answers below are good -- but please be careful with this.  Directly putting this kind of data into a SQL query can open you up to SQL injection attacks.  Use an ORM framework, or use a PreparedStatement rather than directly inserting the string value into a JDBC query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast:

```
String username = (String) session.getAttribute("SessionUser");
```

Comment: i doubt he wants to do this, but fetch the User bean/object, since he wants the user's `email` in the query.

Comment: the variable he's putting in is called "userName", I assume it is a string. Sometimes email=username

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be only adding the user's **name** into the session attribute.

Try setting the entire User object (whatever is the domain object in your case) as follows:

```
session.setAttribute("SessionUser", userObj);
```

Then fetch the object using:

```
UserObj userObj = (UserObj) session.getAttribute("SessionUser");
```

and then use it in your query, something like this:
(assuming you have a getEmail() in the UserObj)

```
String userEmail = userObj.getEmail();
String query = "SELECT title, first, last, email FROM member WHERE email="+ userEmail;
```

Answer (score 0):

if userName attribute is a String object, then you can call it with

```
String userName= (String)session.getAttribute("SessionUser");
String query = "SELECT title, first, last, email FROM member WHERE email="+ userName;
```

or it's bean? then;

```
UserBean user = (UserBean)session.getAttribute("SessionUser");
String query = "SELECT title, first, last, email FROM member WHERE email="+ user.getUserName();
```